# Eloquent is sorting my results on its own

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I was grouping the orders data for a graph and used the following eloquent query to achieve that,

```
Order::selectRaw("CONCAT(monthname(created_at),'-',year(created_at)) as date, count(id) as orders")
->groupBy('date')->get();
```

I got the expected results on my local machine where dates were in normal order, but when running the same thing on production. I get the following output:

```
 Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4607
     all: [
       App\Order {#4564
         date: "April-2020",
         orders: 1,
       },
       App\Order {#4571
         date: "August-2019",
         orders: 4,
       },
       App\Order {#4611
         date: "December-2019",
         orders: 14,
       },
       App\Order {#4570
         date: "February-2020",
         orders: 2,
       },
      App\Order {#4582
         date: "January-2020",
         orders: 8,
       },
       App\Order {#4613
         date: "June-2020",
         orders: 1,
       },
      App\Order {#4565
         date: "March-2020",
         orders: 8,
       },
      App\Order {#4610
         date: "May-2020",
         orders: 10,
       },
      App\Order {#4588
         date: "November-2019",
         orders: 15,
       },
       App\Order {#4599
         date: "October-2019",
         orders: 8,
       },
       App\Order {#4600
         date: "September-2019",
         orders: 11,
       },
     ],
   }
```

It seems to be sorted in alphabetical order but I cannot figure out why. Can anyone tell me what could be the issue?
And yes on my local I use SQL ver 8, and on prod we use SQL 5, could that be the cause? How would I fix  that?

Answer (score 0):

to get riddle of automatic and non-automatic sort, just sort it your self:

first: go to config\database.php and make mysql non-strict:

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),



----------


            'strict' => true, // change it to false
```

then make your query like:

```
Order::selectRaw("created_at,CONCAT(monthname(created_at),'-',year(created_at)) as date, 

count(id) as orders")->orderBy("created_at")
    ->groupByRaw('date')->get();
```

Comment: I tried that but it results in the same output no change.

Comment: oh ... yes , because the date now is string .. i will update my answer

Comment: including created_at in the select won't change the result

Comment: This works but It doesn't give me aggregated results. I wanted results aggerated monthly.

Answer (score 0):

you can order the results output by simply sticking with the raw expression and adding it in the **groupBy()** as well...

**So change this...**

```
->groupBy('date')
```

**To this...**

```
->groupBy(\DB::raw("CONCAT(monthname(created_at),'-',year(created_at)))")
```

```
Order::selectRaw("CONCAT(monthname(created_at),'-',year(created_at)) as date, count(id) as orders")
->groupBy(\DB::raw("CONCAT(monthname(created_at),'-',year(created_at)))")->get();
```

I hope this helps you.

This is what helped me lol...

https://laraveldaily.com/eloquent-trick-group-by-raw-with-boolean-condition/

Comment: I tried this, It doesn't work either. I tried it, seems like I have to aggerate results by simple date and then run a loop through them to group them by month

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work? hmm... have you looked into SQL **views** I use them all the time to build up my datasets the query that view instead of the tables, it helps cos the view is a read-only result set but still works like a table to query, meaning you can do all the logic in the view and then run you query on that view, hope that makes sense...

this is a good example
https://www.guru99.com/views.html#:~:text=VIEWS%20are%20virtual%20tables%20that,one%20table%20or%20many%20tables.